# Fastest way from numeric YYYYMMDD to date and back to numeric YYYYMMDD

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

What I need to optimize is the following process: starting from a numeric value in the form of `yyyymmdd`, convert it to a date, add 3 months to it (not 90 days,the month day must stay the same), and then convert it back to numeric with `yyyymmdd` format. The folowing code achieves just that:

```
library(lubridate)
a = 20180223
b = as.numeric(gsub("-", "", 
                    x = as.character(ymd(a) %m+% months(3)),
                    fixed = TRUE))
b
20180523
```

However, when applying this to a large `data.table` it runs too slow, in my opinion. Below is the code for 1 million rows which runs for 13 seconds on my machine. Is there any way to optimize this? I'm thinking that maybe I don't need to convert to date, but can't wrap my head around it.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

DT = CJ(rep(2016:2018, 1000), 1:12, 1:28)
DT[, StartDate := V1*10000 + V2*100 + V3]

system.time({
  DT[, StartDate_3M :=  as.numeric(gsub("-", "", 
                             x = as.character(ymd(StartDate) %m+% months(3)),
                             fixed = TRUE))]
}) 
   user  system elapsed 
  13.03    0.04   13.18
```

Comment: Why do you need `gsub`? You can try `as.numeric(format(ymd(a) %m+% months(3), format="%Y%m%d"))`

Comment: Get rid of `as.character`, it will save you one function call.

Comment: @MKR running time is down to 10.6 seconds, thank you for the suggestion. Should have remembered that `as.numeric` takes a `format` argument

Comment: Another suggestion is that convert the `(StartDate)` to `ymd` format and keep it in that format. it will remove loads of conversion time which might not be needed in your business logic.

Comment: You can also compute `months(3)` ahead and then use it whenever you need it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Very valid point. One can keep it a variable before data.table operation.

Comment: @MKR I just timed it and the speedup is of around 38%.

Comment: @RuiBarradas now the running time is down to 8.3 seconds.

Comment: Considering that you can't have many dates (by the nature of dates), you'll get instant speedup doing whatever you're doing `by = StartDate`. It's about 3x for the OP example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is a group effort with lots of valuable comments given.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(microbenchmark)

DT = CJ(rep(2016:2018, 100), 1:12, 1:28)
DT[, StartDate := V1*10000 + V2*100 + V3]
```

I made the dataset smaller to allow for a comparison to finish faster on my machine.

Pre-compute the period:

```
diff_3m <- months(3)
```

This suggested code to give you exactly what you want, noting that dates like `20180131` don't go beyond the end of a month so you end up with `20180430` because of the use of the `%m+%` operator from `lubridate`.

```
DT[, StartDate_3M_new := as.numeric(format(ymd(StartDate) %m+% diff_3m, "%Y%m%d"))]
```

Timing on my machine:

```
microbenchmark(
  orig = DT[, StartDate_3M_orig :=  as.numeric(gsub("-", "", 
                                               x = as.character(ymd(StartDate) %m+% months(3)),
                                               fixed = TRUE))],
  new = DT[, StartDate_3M_new := as.numeric(format(ymd(StartDate) %m+% diff_3m, "%Y%m%d"))], times=10)


Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 orig 713.2652 734.5133 798.1475 749.9207 883.2163 912.6070    10
  new 458.8666 483.0388 523.6454 502.4709 518.7074 665.7304    10
```

Of course I don't know if this is the "fastest possible" but I'm thinking the amount of time it would take to re-implement all the little date tricks just for faster computation might exceed the time it takes just to run this code.

Edited to add: here's a cleaned up version (i.e. doesn't throw the warnings) of @BogdanC's arithmetical answer. With leap years for free! The performance is similar.

```
add_months_2 <- function(dt, n_months, month_days) {
  dt[, year := StartDate %/% 10000][
    , month := (StartDate - year * 10000) %/% 100][
    , day := StartDate %% 100][
    , new_month := c(1:12, 1:3)[month + n_months]][
    , leap_year := (!(year %% 4) & (year %% 100)) | !(year %% 400)][
    , max_d := (month_days + leap_year * c(0, 1, rep(0, 10)))[new_month]][  
    , StartDate_PlusM := year * 10000 + new_month * 100 + pmin(day, max_d)]
  dt
}
```

Comment: I agree with the last phrase, the speed-up is quite good. Thank you everyone for the team effort.

Comment: Added a new answer, based only on math operations (and therefore very fast), but it needs some cleaning up.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and had a go at an arithmetic implementation. Not the cleanest I could write, but it's a good starting point. The logic I used for adding one month is the same as `ymd() %m+% months(3)` with the notable exception of not handling leap years (which could also be done, but my business logic doesn't require it).
Full code and benchmark below - it's about 96% faster than my original idea and 94% faster than the group effort (which I still value a lot).

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(microbenchmark)

DT = CJ(rep(2016:2018, 1000), 1:12, 1:28)
DT[, StartDate := V1*10000 + V2*100 + V3]

diff_3m <- months(3)

# arithmetic implementation
month_max_days <- c(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31)

add_months <- function(dt, n_months, month_days) {
  dt[, year := StartDate %/% 10000]
  dt[, month := (StartDate - year * 10000) %/% 100]
  dt[, day := StartDate %% 100]
  dt[month + n_months <= 12, new_month := month + n_months]
  dt[month + n_months > 12, new_month := (month + n_months) ]
  dt[month + n_months > 12, new_month := new_month %% 12 ]
  dt[month + n_months <= 12, StartDate_3M := year * 10000 + new_month * 100 + pmin(day,month_days[new_month])]
  dt[month + n_months > 12, StartDate_3M := (year + (month + n_months) %/% 12) * 10000 + new_month * 100 + pmin(day,month_days[new_month])]
  dt
}

microbenchmark(
  orig = DT[, StartDate_3M_orig :=  as.numeric(gsub("-", "", 
                                                    x = as.character(ymd(StartDate) %m+% months(3)),
                                                    fixed = TRUE))],
  new = DT[, StartDate_3M_new := as.numeric(format(ymd(StartDate) %m+% diff_3m, "%Y%m%d"))],
  new_v2 = add_months(DT,3,month_max_days),
  times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
   expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
   orig 11445.7826 12749.9895 13260.7266 13021.3065 13952.189 15247.221    10
    new  7953.0839  8643.7795 10004.3372  9484.5933 11104.017 13002.025    10
 new_v2   215.5608   309.2308   570.2348   408.0091   761.361  1196.798    10
```

Comment: I've added a version of this code to my answer, which I think tightens the logic and more importantly eliminates the warnings. And I added leap years just because.

Comment: @ngm great, thanks for taking the time to clean this up and adding this to the accepted answer